# How to use a heredoc inside a bash function?

Tags: ubuntu, bash

**Is it possible to insert a *heredoc* inside a bash function?**

The trivial sample below results in an error: `./heredoc_in_function.sh: 10: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")`

```
#!/bin/sh

my_function () {
cat <<HEREDOC
heredoc contents
HEREDOC
}

my_function
```

---

Environment:

- Ubuntu 11.04 (GNU/Linux 2.6.38-8-server x86_64)
- GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: I was under the impression that heredoc was a Perl thing. Is there any reason to believe it would work in BASH?

Comment: @jdw, here docs are present in many languages including bash.

Comment: I see that now. Cool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code looked fine to me, so I copied it line for line and it worked for me on:

- OSX 10.7, bash 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin11).
- Ubuntu 10.04.3, bash 4.1.5(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Is it possible for you to retype the file by hand just to make sure you aren't missing or adding spaces/tabs/etc?

Also, how are you executing it? I did a `chmod +x test.sh` and then `./test.sh`

EDIT: I received the same error as you when I added a space at the beginning of the line with the closing HEREDOC.

Further Note: A trailing space behind the closing `HEREDOC` can also cause this

Comment: Weird, it works now... Vim color syntax highlighting recognized the HEREDOC before (it doesn't if you add that space before the closing HEREDOC) I modified the original script to just use an external file, so I'm not sure what was wrong. It will be much more convenient with heredocs, though!

Comment: Indeed! I love me some heredocs.

Comment: Additionally: A trailing space behind the closing `HEREDOC` can also cause this (These kind of errors are really hard to track down. sigh.)